# Iterating through list of fields using field calculator?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, iterator, python-parser

```
import arcpy, sys, itertools

arcpy.env.workspace = r'path to geodatabase'

fields1 = ['gearqty', 'cnemarea', 'fzone', 'qdsq', 'tensmsq', 'crew', 'nanglers', 'port', 'totalquant', 'trip_days', 'day_fracti', 'gear_days', 'qtykept', 'qtydisc', 'mean_hp', 'sd_hp', 'mean_len', 'sd_len', 'mean_gtons', 'sd_gtons', 'size_fleet', 'anon_id', 'fdays']
fields2 = ['gearqty1', 'cnemare1', 'fzone1', 'qdsq1', 'tensmsq1', 'crew1', 'nangler1', 'port1', 'tquant1', 'tripdays1', 'dayfract1', 'geardays1', 'qtykept1', 'qtydisc1', 'mean_hp1', 'sd_hp1', 'mean_len1', 'sd_len1', 'mean_gton1', 'sd_gtons1', 'sizefleet1', 'anonid1', 'fdays1']

# add new fields of type LONG
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    for b in fields2:
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, b, "LONG")

# calculate LONG fields from STR fields
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): 
    for a, b in itertools.izip(fields1, fields2):
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, b, !a!) 

# delete all unnecessary string attributes
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    for a in fields1:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, a)
```

The list of fields, `fields1`, is all string data, but it should be numeric.  The first code block successfully created new LONG attributes using the names provided by `fields2`.

The second part is where I'm having trouble.  I just need the new `fields2` attributes to be calculated from the old `fields1` attributes.

The third section should delete all of the attributes from `fields1`, as they are useless to me as strings.  I haven't been able to test that part yet.

I've been testing this on one shapefile, but there will be 20+ shapefiles in the geodatabase.

Comment: what was the error you got when testing the second part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!a!` is not valid Python. Is this a typo?

[Calculate Field](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field.htm) defaults to the VB parser, so you'll want to change that to Python.

Something like the following should work: [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) for reference.

```
arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, b, "!{}!".format(a), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

To simplify things, you can combine all your for loops into one:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    for a, b in itertools.izip(fields1, fields2):
        # add new fields of type LONG
        # calculate LONG fields from STR fields
        # delete all unnecessary string attributes
        arcpy.AddField_management(fc, b, "LONG")
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, b, "!{}!".format(a), "PYTHON_9.3")
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, a)
```